# PSModulePath overruled after Microsoft.VSCode_profile.ps1 has run

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I have the same problem many of you may have, which is that our Windows profile is on a network drive and we don't want that as the default place for our PS modules.

In order to automate stuff, I created a script to automatically change the `$env:PSModulePath` variable when the powershell extension starts in VSCode.

So I went ahead and created the profile script as indicated by `$PROFILE`, and in that script I change the environment variable value.

However, some other setting or script seems to put it back automatically. What other profile or script is running *after* `Microsoft.VSCode_profile.ps1` has run ?

In `Microsoft.VSCode_profile.ps1`:

```
<code here manipulating $env:PSModulePath>
Write-Output "Module Path at the end of Microsoft.VSCode_profile.ps1: "
Write-Output $env:PSModulePath
```

So when I start the extension, the terminal outputs as expected:

```
PowerShell Extension v2023.8.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.

https://aka.ms/vscode-powershell
Type 'help' to get help.

Module Path at the end of Microsoft.VSCode_profile.ps1: 
C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\Powershell\Modules;C:\Program Files\PowerShell\Modules;<etc>
```

However, when I check the value of the module path in that intergrated terminal, the UNC path is reinserted:

```
PS> $env:PSModulePath
\\<server>\<homedir>\Data\My Documents\PowerShell\Modules;C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\Powershell\Modules;<etc>
```

So some additional configuration or script seems to run *after Microsoft.VSCode_profile.ps1*? How could I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: There are two `Microsoft.VSCode_profile.ps1` scripts. `$PROFILE | Get-Member -Type NoteProperty`

Comment: That's right, and I'm using the `CurrentUserCurrentHost` profile, because according to the [about Profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7.3) doc, that's the one which is executed last